# Python - Pandas new DF column based on multiple conditions and null checks

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe based on several conditions.  Below I have included how I would do this in SQL using a case statement but I keep running into walls with the Python/Pandas version.

SQL equivelent of what I hope to acheive:

```
select t.Apply_To,
       t.Comment_Code,

       Case when t.Apply_To is null and t.Comment_Code is null then 'Worked'
            when t.Apply_To is null then t.Comment_Code
            else t.Apply_To
       End as Hours

from table as t
```

Thanks in advance for any sugestions you may have.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use `numpy`, try something as below with `where`:

```
import numpy as np

df['new_col'] = np.where( (df['Apply_To'].isnull()) & (df['Comment_Code'].isnull()),'worked', # when both Null
                         np.where(df['Apply_To'].isnull(),df['Comment_Code'],                 # when Apply_To is Null
                         df['Apply_To']))                                                     # else
```

- [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)